# Python - How to sort the rows in a file to match another file sort order

Tags: python-3.x, matching

I have two files: A & B.

File A is tab delimited and has a particular sort order. I want to sort all the rows in File B so that the all the rows in both files match perfectly.

Here is the format of File A (The file that is sorted):

```
#chr    #start      #end        #name                     #score #strand 
chr1    161427010   161427243   Larp7-Chip.MACS2_peak_9704  0.0 .
chr1    161423805   161424053   Larp7-Chip.MACS2_peak_9703  0.0 .
chr1    161429385   161429489   Larp7-Chip.MACS2_peak_9705  0.0 .
```

Here is the format of File B (The file I want to sort):

```
#chr    #start      #end        #name         #score #strand  #genechr #genestart #geneend #genename #genescore #genestrand
chr1    1057669 1058006 Larp7-Chip.MACS2_peak_175   0   .   chr1    1017198 1051736 C1orf159    0   -
chr1    1058881 1058914 Larp7-Chip.MACS2_peak_176   0   .   chr1    1017198 1051736 C1orf159    0   -
chr1    1063389 1063653 Larp7-Chip.MACS2_peak_181   0   .   chr1    1072397 1079434 LINC01342   0   +
```

As you can see File B has more information than File A, which is why I need to match the sort orders so that I can then awk the important information from File B.

Essentially my output (we will call it File C) should look like this:

```
#chr    #start      #end        #name                     #score #strand  #genechr #genestart #geneend #genename #genescore #genestrand
chr1    161427010   161427243   Larp7-Chip.MACS2_peak_9704  0   .   chr1    161475205   161489360   FCGR2A  0   +
chr1    161423805   161424053   Larp7-Chip.MACS2_peak_9703  0   .   chr1    161475205   161489360   FCGR2A  0   +
chr1    161429385   161429489   Larp7-Chip.MACS2_peak_9705  0   .   chr1    161475205   161489360   FCGR2A  0   +
```

**NOTE**: I CANNOT use the fourth column to match and sort the files. There are multiple duplicates and thus would cause a problem. The sort order has to be matched by the first three columns.

**EDIT**: For clarity, File A has information about enhancer regions in the human genome. File B has the same enhancer information, but has extra information regarding the nearby associated gene to each enhancer region.

I want to output a new file that has all the information in File B, but follows the same row order as File A. The number of items is identical in both.

Is this possible to do in Python 3? I am quite new to programming, but with a bit of help I should be able to get this working. It is also a really common task I do at work so having this script laying around for the future would be awesome!

Thank you!

Comment: Sort by what? I do not understand the order...

Comment: The first 6 columns are meant to show positions of enhancer regions in the human genome. The second set of 6 columns show their associated nearby genes.


I want to sort so that the output file has the same row order (same first 6 columns) as File A, but has the information of the associated gene from File B. I put up an EDIT in the main post to try and clarify a bit, i'm sorry if this doesn't completely help.

Comment: It might be easier (and more helpful to understand the question) if you give names  of the columns in each file format. Currently you refer to *the first three columns* which contain different data in both files. Think back relational databases: Identify a candidate key.

Comment: @dhke I agree, most of the tools I use strip out headers so this is why they aren't included. I have gone ahead and added them in the original post. It's important to note that the first three columns in both files contains the exact same data, just ordered differently in the files. So row 1 in File A might be row 1000 in File B. This is why my example does not show the same data. But the first six columns in both files are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the first 6 cols are enough to uniquely identify your record:

```
def getKey (x):
  keys = x.split()[0:6]
  keys[4] = float(keys[4])
  return tuple(keys)
rows_of_fileB = dict( [ getKey(r), r] for r in fileB)
for row in fileA:
  print( rows_of_fileB[getKey(row)] )
```

Comment: I am getting a 

    `KeyError: getKey = lambda x: tuple(x.split()[0:6])
    rows_of_fileB = dict( [ getKey(r), r] for r in fileB)
    for row in fileA:
      print( rows_of_fileB[getKey(row)] )`

at line 7.

This could be because I am opening my files incorrectly. I am using `FileA = open("FileA.txt")`and `FileB = open("FileB.txt")`. I am quite new to python so this may be inappropriate. EDIT: Yes your assumption of the first 6 cols being enough to identify a record is correct.

Comment: Maybe there exist some rows in file A that have no corresponding rows in file B (the first 6 cols do not match). The error message will give you the first 6 cols of that row.

Comment: Hmm I actually think the difference might be that File A has a float 0.0 score, and file B has a int 0 score. I'll fix this and rerun.

Comment: This appeared to be the problem. The code works perfectly now. I just need to figure out how to write out the output :3 any advice?. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like I managed to do it by touching a empty file and opening it as writeable and simply removing your print statement. Let me know if this is fine. Thanks again!

Comment: For output :3 in file A change the print line to `print( " ".join(row.split()[0:3]) + rows_of_fileB[getKey(row)] )`

Comment: For writing to fileC: `fileC=open('fileC.txt','w'); ... fileC.write( ... + '\n')`